# 画像の表示位置がずれる

Tags: objective-c

下のコードに記してある`ImageScaleViewController`に遷移した時、画像の位置を中心に表示させたいのですが、中心から少し下にずれてしまいます。メンバ変数の`scaleImageView`には`ImageScaleViewController`に遷移する前の`ViewController`にある画像が入っています。
そしてそれを`self.view addSubview`すると画面の中心に画像が表示されるのですが、下のコードのように`ScrollView`に`addSubview`すると中心から少し下にずれます。これはどういうことなのでしょうか？`Storyboard`の`ScrollView`は中心に配置されています。
どなたかこの原因が分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
UIImageView *scaleImageView;

@implementation ImageScaleViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    scaleImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.scaleImageView.center.x - self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.width / 2, self.scaleImageView.center.y - self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.height / 2, self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.width, self.scaleImageView.bounds.size.height)];
    scaleImageView.image = self.scaleImageView.image;

    [self.scrollView addSubview:scaleImageView];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcodeの設定で、その画面のViewControllerのAdjust Scroll View Insetsはどうなってるでしょうか？

[image: Adjust Scroll View Insets]

ここのチェックを外すことで、思った通りに動作するようになるかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。チェックと外すことで下にズレることなく表示されました！ありがとうございます！